# Cant change background color of button

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Im using a bootstrap button:

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-info navbar-btn navbar-right" id="logg">Sign in</button>
```

I cant change the color of the button by using `background-color` in css, the color remains the same.

However, Im able to change the `border-color`. Why am I not able to change the background color of the button?

I even had some problems with coloring a bootstrap `navbar`. I couldnt use `border-color` so I used `background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom,someColorHere 0,anotherColorHere 100%);`

Is there any other way to change the background color of bootstrap components?

I am currently working on a maven/web application with JSF framework on Netbeans.

Comment: Did you put your css after the bootstrap css?

Comment: @Christina no I did put if before. Does it matter in which order you put them?

Comment: Yes, of course it matters. The C in CSS is cascading. So you can write a class background-color:yellow BEFORE a background-color:red and red will always take over.

Comment: Wiki: CSS specifies a priority scheme to determine which style rules apply if more than one rule matches against a particular element. In this so-called cascade, priorities or weights are calculated and assigned to rules, so that the results are predictable.

Comment: Do you need a gradient color for the button?

Comment: @JayantVarshney yes I was forced to do that, but by removing the link to the optional css theme cdn, I was able to change the background color of the Bootstrap button.

Comment: @Carlton If you still want to use the optional css, try to place the optional css link before bootstrap so that bootstrap styles can override the previous one. I hope this will also work.

Comment: You should post an answer explaining your solution @JayantVarshney

Comment: ok @kolossus posting as answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As we had discussion, it seems that your optional CSS file is overriding the styles of the current Bootstrap CSS which is not letting you to place the button design.

Please put the optional CSS link before the Bootstarp CSS link in your web page. This will work in your case.